# R and PCA Explanation for machine learning

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca, r-caret

I am taking the Practical Machine Learning on Coursera and I am confused with one of the assignments. I want to be very clear that I am not posting because I want someone to give me the answer -- I just want **help to understand what is happening.**

We are learning about PCA and preprocessing. My understanding is that PCA is all about trying to collapse multiple colinear variables together into one factor, and that the PCA algorithm tries to find the best linear combination of these while using the least number of variables. For example, if I have 5 correlated highly variables, the PCA might find that just using 4 of them in a certain combination explains the most variance. Then, when you do the training, it applies whatever that combination of variables and coefficients was a single predictor instead of the individual variables (is that right)?

What I am having trouble understanding is what is happening behind the scenes. For example, in a lecture, there are 58 variables in a dataset (the 58th is the DV) and we are trying to use PCA for prediction. I am trying to understand what the code does and what sort of objects it is creating, and this is where I could use some help. Below is the code and my annotations that I think explain what is happening -- can someone correct me? This is all in the lecture, but the explanation was not very clear.

1. Goes through all 57 potential predictors, and finds the best set of 2 predictors that explain the most variance. Creates an object ?????

`preProc <- preProcess(log10(training[,-58]+1),method="pca",pcaComp=2)`

2. I have no idea what this line really does

`trainPC <- predict(preProc,log10(training[,-58]+1))`

3. Tries to fit the PCA model on the training data to predict TYPE?

`modelFit <- train(training$type ~ .,method="glm",data=trainPC)`

I am trying to apply this "knowledge" to a quiz question, which is explained below. **I don't want the answer**, just an explanation of what the code is doing.

**ACTUAL QUIZ QUESTION**

Load the Alzheimer's disease data using the commands:

```
library(caret)
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
set.seed(3433)
data(AlzheimerDisease)
adData = data.frame(diagnosis,predictors)
inTrain = createDataPartition(adData$diagnosis, p = 3/4)[[1]]
training = adData[ inTrain,]
testing = adData[-inTrain,]
```

Create a training data set consisting of only the predictors with variable names beginning with IL and the diagnosis. Build two predictive models, one using the predictors as they are and one using PCA with principal components explaining 80% of the variance in the predictors. Use method="glm" in the train function. What is the accuracy of each method in the test set? Which is more accurate?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the help?  (`?preProcess`, `?predict`, `?train`, `?createDataPartition`) R documentation isn't always the easiest to understand, but it can give you a starting point.

Comment: I have not, and it's less about understanding the programming for right now and more about understanding the concepts of PCA and what it "happening" in terms of objects that are created and how they are applied together.

Comment: You will find this post on [PCA and k-fold cross-validation in caret package in R](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46216/pca-and-k-fold-cross-validation-in-caret-package-in-r) useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can read about caret in detail here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf

1) Not exactly, you are creating PCA preprocessing model, which is stored in preProc now, it will combine all 57 different predictors into 2 predictors with some weights (every new feature is different linear combination of original features), keeping as much as possible of variance.

2) And now you are applying transformation computed on previous step to your features, trainPC now contains only 2 features.

3) Yes, at this point you are fitting "glm" Generalized Linear Model, which itself is maybe classification or regression task (not transformation of features as in previous step, but you still can use predict as in previous step to predict values).
https://topepo.github.io/caret/Generalized_Linear_Model.html

Comment: So step 1 is creating essentially 2 variables with a certain set of weights.

Step 2 is applying those predictors with those weights to the actual data.

Step 3 is trying to use the new data using the PC to actually predict the outcome variable. 

Does that seem right?